# Python - Efficiency - Check if list is empty before calling filter()?

Tags: python, performance, filter, processing-efficiency

I have a list of files, which I need to filter for acceptable file-types (eg. keep only ".txt" files). Then, I "do stuff" with the final list if and only if it is not empty. My original code (with toy list) is this:

```
files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.jpg"]
if files:
    files[:] = filter(check_filetype, files)
    if files:
         # do something with remaining .txt files
```

However, I am curious if the first "if" statement is necessary, to check if this list is empty before filtering. I tested and `filter()` will accept (and return) an empty list.

So what is more efficient, an extra branch in the first "if" statement, or filtering an empty list? I'm leaning towards removing the first "if" statement.

Comment: me too. since an empty list will not throw an error or mess anything up, it is safe to remove the first `if` - if you have another way of handling the empty lists.

Comment: At most you'd save yourself the overhead of one function call, which in the grant scheme of things is nothing. Removing the `if` would make the code simpler though, which trumps one wasted CPU cycle anytime.

Comment: Builtin filter already handles empty list internally. For me first if is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can remove the first `if` statement. Note also you can just use a list comprehension, which is often considered more Pythonic. It should, at least, be more efficient for larger lists versus `filter` + a custom function:

```
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
files = [fn for fn in files if check_filetype(fn)]

if files:
    # do something
```